# Discord.py nickname updater not working in loop for unknown reasons, no errors

Tags: python, discord

thank you in advance for your help!

My goal is to edit the nickname of any user in the server which does not comply with the formatting I specify.

The following loop **works perfectly fine** without the line `await user.edit(nick=f"SAS{jsonPilotID} - {jsonName}")`, which is the one supposed to edit the actual nickname. However, when I add the line, the loop just **blocks itself** on the first user it encounters and does not want to advance. **No errors** are thrown and no nicknames are edited either.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=LoopTimer)
async def NicknameUpdater(msg):
    url = rankUrl

    req = requests.post(url)
    req = json.loads(req.text)

    y = msg.guild.members

    print("Start nickname edit loop \n")

    for user in y:
        for i in req['records']:
            if not i['discordid'] == None:
                jsonDiscordID = int(i['discordid'])
                jsonName = i['firstname']
                jsonPilot = i['pilotid']
                if len(jsonPilot) == 1:
                    userPilotIDZero = "000"
                elif len(jsonPilot) == 2:
                    userPilotIDZero = "00"
                elif len(jsonPilot) == 3:
                    userPilotIDZero = "0"
                elif len(jsonPilot) == 4:
                    userPilotIDZero = ""

                jsonPilotID = userPilotIDZero + jsonPilot

                if jsonDiscordID == user.id:

                    print(f"User {user} discord ID {user.id} name {jsonName}")

                    print(jsonPilotID)

                    print(f"SAS{jsonPilotID} - {jsonName}")

                    if not user.display_name == f"SAS{jsonPilotID} - {jsonName}":
                        await user.edit(nick=f"SAS{jsonPilotID} - {jsonName}")
                        print(f"Changed username for {jsonName} to SAS{jsonPilotID} - {jsonName}")
                    else:
                        print("no need to change nickname.")
            else:
                pass

    t = time.localtime()
    current_time = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", t)

    loopCompleteMessage = f"\n\nNickname edit loop end at {current_time}. Next loop in {LoopTimer} seconds"

    print(loopCompleteMessage)
```

I will be happy to answer any questions.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: How is `msg` being passed to the task? Does your bot have the required permissions to change nicknames?

Comment: Hi! Msg is passed during the startup function and represents the channel where it posts its login status, allowing the bot to then search for members. The issue is not there. The bot also has administrator privileges, therefore yes it can change nicknames